# Training vs test accuracy trade-off

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, validation, overfitting, accuracy

Say I am training a neural network for image classification of cats and dogs, in a dataset of 1000 for example. 
I train the network on 800 examples, and then I test it with the remaining 200 examples, and I get training and test accuracies of **94% and 73%** --> 21% gap

Applying regularization should fix this train-test accuracy gap up to some extent. Would it be right to assume that there is **always** the possibility of a **trade-off** between training accuracy and test accuracy, by incrementing the amount of regularization being applied to the network?

In other words, is it correct to assume that there **exists an specific setting** for my regularization hyperparameters, that would allow to "almost completely" reduce that 21% gap, to something like 1% or 2% gap? At the cost of reducing training accuracy, getting for instance **79%-77%** train and test accuracies.

I've found this other simmilar issue [validation/training accuracy and overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327057/validation-training-accuracy-and-overfitting), however I don't find any of the answers accurate enough to the particular question.

Answer (score 2):

The accuracy gap between train and test data is caused by fitting:

1. noises in train data (hence over-fit)
2. features exist only in train data

The regularisation can control fitting to noises.

But for the second point, you may need a process like feature selection.

Comment: So @Sixiang.Hu, assuming that point 2. does not exist in this case, i.e. training and test data are rather simmilar, would then be always possible to get rid of that noise/overfitting gap by applying the correct amount of regularization?

Comment: Get rid of noise fully is not really practically imo. The reason is "get rid of noise" fully means you can "model" noise ( so that it can be regularized ), which is not practical.  And this is why I used "control fitting to noises" as oppose to "fully get rid of noise".